# What are the practical applications for using square roots modulo a prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I've seen several algorithms for computing square roots modulo a prime number, but  have yet to see a description of a problem that uses a square root modulo a prime number for some practical purpose. I was thinking this may have applications in cryptography, but while I found plenty of a number modulo a prime examples, I did not see any reference to the square root portion.

Comment: Search "zero knowledge proof modular square root", and have a look around.  There can be 4 square roots of $a$ mod $pq$, and Alice can prove to Bob that she knows $p$ and $q$ (without revealing to Bob what $p$ and $q$ are) be repeatedly picking the correct square root of $a$.